# Continuity of a Piecewise Function $ - e^{-1/x }$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Prove the following function is continuous on $[0,1]$:
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{x}} & \text{if} & x \not=0 \\
0 & \text{if} & x=0
\end{cases}
$$

---

My attempt at a proof:

***Proof.*** Consider two cases: showing $f$ is continuous at  (1) $x \not= 0$, and (2) $x = 0$.

(1) If $x \not=0$, take $g(x)= -\frac{1}{x}$, and $q(x) = \mathrm{e}^x$. Then, on $(0,1]$, we have that $f(x) = (q \circ g)(x)$. Both $q$, and $g$ are continuous on $(0,1]$, so $f$ is continuous on $(0,1]$.*

(2) If $x = 0$, we must show $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0) = 0$$
Notice that $f(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ for all $x \not= 0$. Thus, $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{x}}$$

**This is as far as I got** - I don't know how to continue. Is this the right approach? If not, how should I approach the problem?

---

* Take for granted that $-\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $(0,1]$.

Comment: Since $x$ approaches 0 from the right side, i.e. $x$ is positive: $$\lim_{x\to 0}-\frac{1}{x}=-\infty$$ you may continue from here

Comment: And not that $$\lim_{x\to x_0} f\circ g(x)=f\left(\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=1/x$ so that $u\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0^+$.
Then $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^+}e^{-1/x} = \lim\limits_{u\rightarrow\infty}e^{-u} = \lim\limits_{u\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{e^u} = 0$

Comment: Found this question while trying to figure out how to prove that the same function is $C^{\infty}$, i.e. that it has partial derivatives of all orders...